# Android orientation change even after locking it in system settings

Tags: android, orientation, settings, screen-lock

as in the topic, ive got a trouble with locking screen orientation after its been locked in device's settings. Its a landscape app. Ive read couple threads about similar problem but havent got any revelant answer.
Thanks in advance
Mac

Comment: you want your app to be displayed in landscape only ?

Comment: ye, the thing is i want it to flip from landscape rigth to landscape left, not when the device has it locked though

Answer (score 0):

You can add **android:screenOrientation="landscape"** in your activity tag to specify the mode of screen orientation in your manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xyz.myapp.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

Add **setRequestedOrientation** in the **onCreate** method like below

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
```

Comment: ive got it set as SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE, cuz I want it to be rotable whenever the device's setting for "auto rotate" is on, and to keep the landscape rotation whenever its off

Answer (score 0):

This would set to landscape if auto_rotate is off, otherwise if would rotate normally as long as it wasn't set to land/port in the manifest.

```
if(android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) != 1){
   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```